# KDE-dolphin trashcan on second HDD

Tags: kde, trash, dolphin

From KDE I use only dolphin.
I've pulled out second hdd for a couple of days (also changed `fstab`). Now I put it back and dolphin won't "see" `/hdd2/.Trash-1000/` and if I delete file `/hdd2/file1` it moves to `~/.local/share/Trash/` but should move to `/hdd2/.Trash-1000/`

How do I point dolphin to use right trash-dir?

Comment: What makes you think that dolphin uses a different trash per hard drive?

Comment: It did use different trash-dirs for over a year till I pulled out hdd 2 days ago.

Comment: Oh. Really? Sounds strange but fair enough then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `.Trash-uid` has to be with 700 permissions. Strangely, but it won't work with 777.